# How to sum a column where row equals a certain value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with several columns. The relevant ones are 'Search term' and 'Clicks'. 'Search term' might be something like "widget maker" or "widget app". Because there will undoubtedly be multiple entries for each, I want to sum the Clicks for all rows that start with "widget". I've been tinkering with it for hours and this is as close as I've come but it still doesn't work:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/me/widgets.csv', encoding='utf8')

column_names = df.columns.values

df.loc[df['Search term'] == df['Search term'].str.extract(r'^(widget.*)'), ['Clicks']].sum()
```

This is as close as I've come, but it runs VERY slow and returns:

```
Users/me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py:253: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  res_values = method(rvalues)

[insert insanely long Traceback]

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC that you just want a scalar, you could use a mask.

```
data = {
    'Clicks':[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,2,3,4,5],
    'Search term':['t1','t2','t3','t4','widget','widget','t7','t8','t9','t10','widget','t12','t13']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

    Clicks  Search term
0   2   t1
1   3   t2
2   4   t3
3   5   t4
4   6   widget
5   7   widget
6   8   t7
7   9   t8
8   10  t9
9   2   t10
10  3   widget
11  4   t12
12  5   t13

mask = (df['Search term'].astype(str).str.contains('widget'))

the_sum  = df.loc[mask, 'Clicks'].sum()

print(the_sum)

16
```

Comment: That mask only gets me the Search term, not the Clicks, so when I try to run 'the_sum' I get a KeyError on 'Clicks'.

Comment: In my example, clicks was not capitalized. I edited my answer to match your column names. LMK if that doesn't help.

Comment: Edit: I figured out a way around this but my result is None of [Index([(False,False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, ', '1', '1', '4', '1', '1', '1', '1', '4', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '5', '2', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '12', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1',, ...)], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"

Comment: Can you post some sample data? Is your Clicks column numeric?

Comment: Well that output was a sample, and I ran pd.to_numeric both on the original df before making the mask and on the mask itself. mask = (df['Search term'].astype(str).str.startswith('widget'), pd.to_numeric(df['Clicks']))

Comment: I meant can you post a sample df input. It's hard to answer your question without knowing the state of your input data.